# VS2015 - VB/ASP.NET Build fake error: "Type 'XYZ' is not defined" in UserControl code-behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.5, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

Ok guys, this one is not easy...

For the story, I got a old 3.5 ASP.NET/VB.NET website project (ASPX) build on VS2012 that I've upgraded to 4.5 to run well on VS2015.
I'm also trying to remove all the compilations errors that it got, even if the website was working under them (VB.NET is weird...)

During this operation, I've got some unchanged codes that worked well before but they don't let me run anymore.

So, here is the build problem:

I've got a UserControl (`private/UserControls/Fiche/OngletAccueil.ascx`), used in a page (`private/fiche.aspx`), that need some values from the MasterPage (`private/MasterPage.master`).

They all use the same namespace `Vita`, here are some excerpts to understand:

The MasterPage:

```
Namespace Vita

Partial Public Class private_MasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Public _debug As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("debug")

    Public ReadOnly Property ModeDebug As Integer
        Get
            Return _debug
        End Get
    End Property
    ...
```

The UserControl:

```
Namespace Vita

Public Class private_UserControls_Fiche_OngletAccueil
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public ReadOnly Property modeDebug As Integer
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, private_MasterPage).ModeDebug
        End Get
    End Property
    ...
```

The ASPX page:

```
    <%@ Page Async="true" Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/private/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="fiche.aspx.vb" Inherits="Vita.public_fiche" %>

    <%@ Register TagPrefix="Tools" TagName="OngletAccueil" Src="UserControls/Fiche/OngletAccueil.ascx" %>
    ...
```

With that, I got a compilation error about the MasterPage class type in the UserControl:
`Type 'private_MasterPage' is not defined.`on `\private\UserControls\Fiche\OngletAccueil.ascx.vb`

I don't even understand why it don't run the IISexpress when it was ok on previous framework...

I show you the code to make you understand that the code is not really the problem: it seems that the problem come from intelliSense or from the compilation temp files, like if the MasterPage class can't be seen (scope access) by the UserControl because they are not in the same temp assembly.

Before, I've got the same problem with a userControl used into another userControl (which files are saved in exactly the same folder...), but I was able to trick the compilator with a `web.config` setting, it seems to work:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="Tools" src="~/private/UserControls/Fiche/PosteUser.ascx" tagName="PosteUser" />
    <add tagPrefix="Tools" src="~/private/UserControls/Fiche/NotesDeFrais.ascx" tagName="NotesDeFrais" />
    <add tagPrefix="Tools" src="~/private/UserControls/Fiche/Evals_CollaborateursInternes.ascx" tagName="EvalsCollaborateursInternes" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

But here, the MasterPage is not a control, it's a page, I can't use the same trick...

Thx for help guys, I've already spent a lot of time on it and I did analyzed a bunch of Q&A & MSDN docs before post it here, on this you're my last hope :'(

Here some last & useful infomation on the `web.config`:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
...
<compilation debug="true" batch="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
...
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
...
```

Comment: I think this is yet another of the "you can only use ASP.NET x in VS 20yy" - I can only speak about MVC but there you usually can compile just fine on newer versions but Intellisense will stop working correctly

Comment: I would love to know which are the best dev environment for a ASP.NET ASPX WSP.
I missed say something, you have to know that yesterday, my compilation succeeded on VS2015 with 0 errors !

Then, 2 things happened: I changed some files with a Mercurial fusion (CSS, JS and some totally differents files) and I wanted to test my changes but by mistake, I've started building it with VS2012. I closed it, I came back on VS2015, and you know the rest... I cleaned some temp files in AppData but it was not enough to get back to my 0 errors run...

Comment: is this a compiler error or a error shown in intellisense? (you did not post the error itself so I assumed it's intellisense)

Comment: btw: the `Public Class private_...` is killing me ;)

Comment: I think it's extremely hard to diagnose such a problem if you cannot see VS in front of you - is there any chance that you can gut out everything not related to the error (meaning remove everything but those few classes/files) and put the solution/project on some public code-bin so we can have a direct look?

Comment: It's both, I got it on the page code, on the error list and in the build output: `3>F:\Dev\vita\private\UserControls\FicheCRF\OngletAccueil.ascx.vb(17,0): erreur BC30002: Type 'private_MasterPage' non défini.`
And sorry for this horrible naming, it's an old corporate app, I'm on it only since few months ^^ and believe me, I've seen way more horrible things on this app :D

Comment: don't worry: we all had/wrote those ;)

Comment: lol, I swear it's not me xD ! Anyway, I'm ok to try reproduce a sample project of my code, while that time, here there's a case with some sample code that seems to make the same kind of error than me: http://forums.asp.net/t/1588773.aspx?+Type+ASP+x+is+not+defined+error+for+dynamic+user+control+when+publishing+updateable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I got it, by changing PC...

I think the problem come from compilating the project on different versions of VS.

I did only one compilation of my project on 2012 and then the compilation on 2015 made this unbreakable error...

So even if you purge some temp folders like `AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`, `AppData\Local\Temp\VWDWebCache` or `.vs\project\v14\.suo`, it's not enough.

After some more debug on others things that appeared, I can now compile with 0 errors and publish also after bit more debug. Now I'm on some other problems on runtime, it's still not fully working like before but it's getting closer ;)

**UPDATE**

What I did before worked for the compilation but it didn't solved the runtime (the bug came back on runtime as InvalidCastException).

To solve the runtime, I just checked the Build/Publish option "use fixed naming and single page assemblies" and it solved my case :)

Unckeck also the build (and publish) option "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable"

Here some useful links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479044.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/960707.aspx